# Share Session between Page in Page to Page Request

Tags: asp.net

My application is simple, I have 2 pages:

1. RSSProducer.aspx: A page that generates RSS (XML) feeds
2. RssConsumer.aspx: A page that retrieves the RSS feeds and displays it to the user in a repeater control. To do this I am using the System.Xml.XmlTextReader to fill a DataSet with tables based on the RSS-XML retrieved from the  RSSProducePage. A table within the DataSet is bound to the repeater control.

For example, this is what I have in my RssConsumer.aspx page:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Session("permittedToViewSomeDetail") = True
    Dim url = "http://localhost/DevSite/RSSProducer.aspx"
    Dim reader As New System.Xml.XmlTextReader(url)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ds.ReadXml(reader)
    myRssRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables(2)
    myRssRepeater.DataBind()
  End Sub
```

My problem is that user-authorization details are stored in Session in the RssConsumer page that need to be accessed in the RSSProducer page (in this example it would be Session("permittedToViewSomeDetail") that I need to access in the RSSProducer page); however, the Session identifier is not common between the two. This means that I cannot access the authorization details in the RSSProducer page.

The reason for why is fairly clear to me:

1. User's browser makes a request to
   the RssConsumer page
2. Server generates a Session ID (which is stored in a cookie) if
   there is no existing Session
   Identifer
3. The RSSConsumer requests the RSSProducer page...which generates a
   new Session ID every time because no
   session identifier is ever going to
   be found.

I tried using cookieless session so that I could pass the SessionID via the URL to the RSSProducer page as an experiment but for some reason the XmlTextReader doesn't work well with this method (but the desired shared session does work).

I've hit a brick wall here.
Does anyone know how to share session between pages when one page makes a request to the other?

Thanks,

-Frinny

Comment: how is the rss consumer page requesting the rss producer page? via a redirect on the browser or via some internal code generating an HTTPRequest object?

Comment: It is not clear from your question if the two pages are on the same site or on different domains/subdomains.

Comment: to further understand what you are doing - why cant the user just navigate to rssproducer.aspx directly, and have the browser format the output, or use a stylesheet to format the output?  what is rss consumer doing that makes it necessary?

Comment: I updated my original post to better explain my problem.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: James, the reason the user cannot just navigate to the RssProducer.aspx page is because the have to be authenticated first. The user needs to log-in so that the system generate RSS feeds based on their authorization/access details.

Comment: Sorry for delay in response, but why can't RssProducer.aspx also authenticate the user - and redirect to another error page if they aren't authenticated?  The session identifier should be common to any request made by the user, unless the user isn't actually requesting the page - i.e. you are using an internal HTTPRequest. If you are doing this then that seems very odd... whatever code is running in RSSProducer can equally well run in RSSConsumer - which is another way of saying just make them the same page....

Comment: The request to RSSProducer was not being made by the user...the XmlTextReader was retrieving the RSS-XML from the RSSProducer (I even posted the code that does this). I gave up on this approach and took a different one. Thank you very much for your time and recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a different approach to solving this problem. I moved the code out of the RssProducer.aspx page into the RssConsumer.aspx page. I am now able to apply the correct authorization to the feature and it's actually more efficient this way because I don't need to produce/consume RSS-XML any more.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me with this.

-Frinny